# pyqtgraph examples not working with python 3.10.12 & PyQt6 (6.5.2) installed

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, pyqt6

I have recently updated my system to python 3.10.12 with PyQt6 and pyqtgraph version 0.13.3 but I can't get any of the code examples to work with this message always appearing:

```py
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqtgraph.Qt'; 'pyqtgraph' is not a package
```

This is a shame as I have some pyqtgraph apps based on 0.10.x which worked fine with PyQt5 installed but following this update I can't get any of them to work along with example code from: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/tree/master/pyqtgraph/examples

Is there an incompatability between pyqtgraph.Qt imports and PyQt6 perhaps? I can't see an easy way of getting it to work without changing a lot of the code?

Comment: The error says that the package `pyqtgraph` wasn't installed. Did you install it in a different virtual environment perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no it is installed (listed under pip list: pyqtgraph              0.13.3) and I just tried again - something odd going on with package manager perhaps?

Comment: If you installed it in the wrong virtual environment it won't appear in your code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using WSL2 - but I have installed PIP, then PyQt6 then pyqtgraph and all dependencies for my app in the same terminal window and session but I still get this problem

Comment: I can't reproduce this. In a new virtual environment, after installing both pyqtgraph and PyQT6, the modules are recognized

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for trying, yes I will try again with a new venv to see what is going on

Comment: Unless you want to use the compatibility layer allowing fallbacks for PySide and PyQt, you should normally directly import the submodules directly from PyQt (or PySide), and preferably *before* importing pyqtgraph. Note that since PyQt6 there is no `PyQt.Qt` module anymore, and you should access the submodules directly.